# Can counting sort sort decimal values?

Tags: sorting

Can Counting Sort sort decimal values? I'm just started learning java recently and I'm unsure. Does anyone know if it can or not?

[image]

Comment: What would `k` be for an array of "decimal" values?

Answer (score 1):

Counting Sort only works because you know exactly how many elements there are in the array, and because each index in an array represents an integer of the same value. The array `[1, 2, 0, 2, 1]` can be represented as `[1, 2, 2]` in the middle stage of the sort. There is one 0, two 1s, and two 2s.

This is not possible in the same way with decimals. If you could ensure a certain level of precision I suppose you could add a slot for each potential value. For example, if all the decimals were rounded to the nearest tenth you would need at 10 slots for each whole number plus 1 slot for 0: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0

```
// the original array
[0.1, 1.1, 0.7, 1.4, 0.5, 0.7]


// after the counting step

// 0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9
[   0    1    0    0    0    1    0    2    0    0

// 1.1  1.2  1.2  1.3  1.4  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9
    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0 ]

// when expanded to the sorted array

[0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.7, 1.1, 1.4]
```

So for a sort with a max value of N, the size of the counting array (K) would be N * 10. So k = 10N. This is obviously not true counting sort, since the counting step would be more complex since each value cannot be so easily mapped to an index.

So while theoretically possible and would have the same time complexity, it would not be a "true" counting sort while also taking up FAR more memory space to be practical, especially when sorting large number ranges with high precision, and being less flexible than other sorting algorithms. You would be better off using most any other sorting algorithm.

Comment: I don't understand your argument why this would not be "true" counting sort or why it would take up "FAR more memory space". For instance, there is fundamentally no difference between count-sorting an array containing integers between 0 and 10000, and an array containing percentages with precision up to 0.01%.

Comment: @Stef I only say not True since counting sort is generally used for integers, but you're right no there is not a great difference between the logic.

Comment: @Stef I mean it would use more memory with the same min and max range. Sorting integers from 0-10 would only need 10 integers worth of memory, but sorting decimals to 0.01 precision would required 100N times as much memory due to the additional slots to hold all of the additional potential values that the increased precision provides (0.01, 0.02, 0.03, etc). So more decimal precision requires more memory to be allocated to the intermediary counting array

Comment: yes, so the downline is that the space and time complexity are an increasing functin of the **size** of the numbers (in bits, or in decimals, or whatever format), not on their **magnitude**. This makes a lot of sense, especially if the values have units - what is the difference between expressing a value in kilograms or in grams or in tons?

Comment: @Stef good point I didn't make it clear enough that its the range and precision that's important rather than the size. The unit itself only matters in that you want to use the largest applicable unit so as to only sort number from 1 - 2 tons rather than 1,000 - 2,000 pounds. But this is the same for count sort with ints so its not a new consideration when count sorting with decimals.